# boxplot scatterplot from r to python

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, seaborn

I am trying to port some code from R to python, but I am encountering some difficulties with plotting.

The simplest example I can give is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
df1=data.frame(a_class=letters[1:10], vals=sample(10, replace=TRUE))


ggplot(df1, aes(x=0, y=vals))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  geom_jitter(aes(shape=a_class, color=a_class), height = 0)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = 1:nrow(df1))
```

This code produces this image (it may be slightly different each time since sample is random).

[image]

How can I achieve this in seaborn or matplotlib?
I tried:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a_class": list("abcdefghij"), "vals": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
sns.boxplot(x=0, y="vals", data=df1)
sns.stripplot(x=0, y="vals", data=df1, jitter=True, hue="a_class", palette="Set1")
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5696\451374326.py in <module>
      1 df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a_class": list("abcdefghij"), "vals": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
      2 
----> 3 sns.boxplot(x=0, y="vals", data=df1)
      4 sns.stripplot(x=0, y="vals", data=df1, jitter=True, hue="a_class", palette="Set1")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in boxplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth, whis, ax, **kwargs)
   2241 ):
   2242 
-> 2243     plotter = _BoxPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   2244                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
   2245                           width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth)
    404                  width, dodge, fliersize, linewidth):
    405 
--> 406         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    407         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    408 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    154 
    155             # Figure out the plotting orientation
--> 156             orient = infer_orient(
    157                 x, y, orient, require_numeric=self.require_numeric
    158             )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py in infer_orient(x, y, orient, require_numeric)
   1309     """
   1310 
-> 1311     x_type = None if x is None else variable_type(x)
   1312     y_type = None if y is None else variable_type(y)
   1313 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py in variable_type(vector, boolean_type)
   1227 
   1228     # Special-case all-na data, which is always "numeric"
-> 1229     if pd.isna(vector).all():
   1230         return "numeric"
   1231 

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: You can try `x = [""]*len(df)` in both cases.  Seaborn needs as many x as y values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does help. How do I move the legend outside the plot though?

Comment: Found:
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
THanks a lot anyway.

Comment: The code would be better readable if instead of `loc=2` you would use `loc="upper left"`.  Note that seaborn also has `sns.movelegend`, to move a seaborn generated legend, for which `plt.legend` doesn't always work well.